# Como puedo mostrar hora actual en diferente EDITEX

Tags: android-studio

[image]

Por ejemplo, Quiero  que al presionar cualquier imagen de hora marque la hora correcta , Al pasar minutos si vuelvo a presionar algún otro Editext Marca la primer hora no la actual

[image]

Ejemplo presione en la primera me marcó 10:48, pasaron unos minutos y me marca las mismas 10:48 sabiendo que son las  11:498

```
 private void obtenerHora() {
        TimePickerDialog recogerHora = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                String horaFormateada = (hourOfDay < 9) ? String.valueOf(CERO + hourOfDay) : String.valueOf(hourOfDay);
                String minutoFormateado = (minute < 9) ? String.valueOf(CERO + minute) : String.valueOf(minute);

                String AM_PM;
                if (hourOfDay < 12) {
                    AM_PM = "a.m.";
                } else {
                    AM_PM = "p.m.";
                }

                editTextDesg.setText(horaFormateada + DOS_PUNTOS + minutoFormateado + " " + AM_PM);
            }

        }, hora, minuto, false);

        recogerHora.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu método solo podrá obtener la hora  a partir de abrir el `TimePickerDialog` , si este no se abre y no seleccionas una hora diferente simplemente no podrá cambiar la hora.

Te sugiero cambies el método por:

```
private String obtenerHora() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour24hrs = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int hour12hrs = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    String AM_PM = "";
    if (hour24hrs < 12) {
        AM_PM = "a.m.";
    } else {
        AM_PM = "p.m.";
    }
    return hour24hrs + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + AM_PM;
}
```

Este método lo puedes llamar cuando des clic a la imagen indicando en que `EditText` deseas poner la hora:

```
 editText.setText(obtenerHora());
```